# Specify Home Directory: Partitioned Disk: Fresh Re-Install: Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.02

Tags: boot, partitioning, gnome, mount, home-directory

I ran into serious problems with my previous Ubuntu installation. I'm now doing a fresh install (Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.02) on an already partitioned disk.

I go to "Installation Type: Something Else" Then I see my partitioned disk. I know that:
"/dev/sda5 ... ext4 ... 34999MB" will be the Ubuntu Gnome OS - Does that mean that it will be "Device for bootloader installation"?
"/dev/sda2 ... swap ... 4099MB" will be the swap
"/dev/sda3 ... ext4 ... 461006MB" is what I want to be my home directory. This has all my data. It's backed up, but I still don't want to format it.

I think that I need to set
"/dev/sda5" to be root "/" and
"/dev/sda3" to be home "/home"

How do I do that?
Gallery of screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9uhR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Make dev/sda3 your /home and dev/sda5 /.

Too not format the /home partition, there are some small boxes on the installer under the option "format?"

Make SURE dev/sda3 is NOT checked and dev/sda5 IS checked.

This will reinstall the system but leave your /home the same as it was in the previous install.

Answer (score 0):

- dev/sda5 is your root partition
- dev/sda3 is your home partition

follow this steps to safely install ubuntu without losing your data

[image]

- *sda1 (ext4)* - is my root partition
  [image]
- *sda6 (ext4)* - is my home partition(usually it had large partition and used more MB)
- *sda5 **swap** (ext4)* - is my swapiness partition

1.now select home partition (your sda3 but my sda6)
and go to change

[image]

2.now select

- use as-ext4 journalist file system
- **don't tick to format the partition**
- select mount point as home [/home]

[image]

3.now select your root partition and go to change

4.now select

- use as-ext4 journalist file system
- now you can tick to format the partition
- select mount point as root [/][image]

5.now select root partition to boot loader(your sda5)

[image]

now you can install ubuntu without losing data